# How to know the "position" of a number in an "array"?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having kind of a problem to make this question since I don't know if the terms that I'm using are correct, so bear in mind that maybe they aren't, so "array" and "position" maybe aren't what I mean. I worked a lot on the explanation, trying to make as simple as possible, I really hope it's helpful.

I have a Google Spreadsheet with twenty three sheets. All of them are related to a specific season of the Barclays Premier League and one is for calculation purposes.

I'm calculating now how high in the attacking ranks, a team that had the 10th best defense was. It looks like this:

```
1          A      |             B                 |         C         |         D       | 
2        Season   | 10th Defense (Goals Conceded) | Finished Position | Attack Position |
3       1992-93   |             55                |         5         |         ?       |
```

My problem is that unlike B3, where I get the quantity of the goals conceded, in D3 I don't want the same thing. What I'm trying to do is it to get the "array" of goals by each team in '1992-93'!G1:G23 and it to tell me where their attack finished (1st, 2nd, etc). So it needs to get the position of the team in C3 to know which attack belonged to the team and them look on '1992-93'!G1:G23 to know the position of the attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `RANK` and `INDEX`.

```
RANK(INDEX('1992-93'!G1:G23,C3),'1992-93'!G1:G23)
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I'm getting "Did not find value '5' in HLOOKUP evaluation' error (#N/A), I checked the sheet and it's there. Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: Both MATCH options returned the same thing as HLOOKUP. Perhaps I forgot to mention something by not knowing the importance of it?

Comment: Let's say: if I just get the array on '1992-93'G1:G23, how do I calculate the position of the attack that I want (in this case, '1992- 93'!G6)? I didn't want to simplify so much since I'll have to do it manually everytime that I want to calculate it, but at least is a start, I guess?

Comment: On my question in the comment above, I found that RANK is the function that can deliver me this. I'll try to combine it to see if I can get what I'm looking for. Thank you so far.

Comment: I'll post as a comment because I'm having a bit of a stab in the dark (sharing an illustrative ss would be helpful) but perhaps: `=RANK(INDEX('1992-93'!G1:G23,C3),'1992-93'!G1:G23)`

Comment: Hi, @AdamL, it worked, thank you. I tried to edit Paul's Draper answer to include yours and the other solution that I came by, but since I'm still new here I can't. Can you post your answer, please, and then I add my other solution as a comment? Thank you!